# bing channel submit for review error

Tags: botframework, bing

I am tring to connect my demo bot to Bing Channel, by I am getting an error:

> Your bot did not respond to our Ping request with a success code. 
>   Please verify your bot is running and responsive before Publishing
>   your bot. The error received from your bot was:
>   InternalServerError(500), Internal Server Error

All my other channels are working fine: (skype, facebook, telegram, direct line).

Answer (score 0):

The bot should respond to Pings with an http status 200.  If the bot responds to a Ping with a message, or does not respond with a status 200, some channels will log an exception.

C# example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    else if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
        //Do nothin with Ping.  Return .OK status below
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```